# Remove italic from memoir headings pagestyle

Tags: formatting, header-footer, memoir

I am using the `memoir` class for my thesis and I'd like to stop the headings from being italic in the page headers. 
I am using the `headings` page style, I found out how to remove the uppercase heads but I can't find out how to get it not italic.

Any suggestion?

As of now (with the italic text), I am doing this:

```
\makeheadrule{headings}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}
\addtopsmarks{headings}{
  \nouppercaseheads
}{
  \createmark{chapter}{both}{shownumber}{}{. \space}
  \createmark{section}{right}{shownumber}{}{. \space}
}
\setsecnumdepth{section}
\pagestyle{headings}
```

Comment: could you include your code?

Comment: I hope the headings part is enough!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the following code to your preamble

```
\makeevenhead{headings}{\thepage}{}{\leftmark}
\makeoddhead{headings}{\rightmark}{}{\thepage}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly! (it didn't even cross my mind to use those commands, I am still a novice)