# Incomplete \iffalse error and "Tex capacity exceeded"

Tags: biblatex, xetex, texlive

I'm getting these error messages when I try to compile (XeLaTeX) my dissertation on texpad for Mac OS/X running TexLive2015, this is what I get:

```
./Dissertation.tex:94: Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 290.
<inserted text> 
                \fi 
l.94 \begin{document}

./Dissertation.tex:94: TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\blx@dopreamblecmds ->\do \blx@dopreamblecmds 
                                              \do \blx@onlypreamble 
l.94 \begin{document}

No pages of output.
```

I never had this problem before. It used to work like a charm until I added one footnote. One of the issues is clearly related to my bibliography, and in fact, a few lines above I can read:

```
Package biblatex Warning: File 'Dissertation.bbl' is wrong format version - expected 2.5.
```

...

```
Package biblatex Warning: The following entry could not be found
(biblatex)                in the database:
(biblatex)                type X <return> to quit.
(biblatex)                Please verify the spelling and rerun
(biblatex)                LaTeX afterwards.
```

and at the end of the dissertation.bbl file I find this error:

```
 \endentry
  \endsortlist
  \missing{type  X <return>  to quit.}\GenericError {               }{LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item}{See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.}{Try typing  <return>  to proceed.\MessageBreak If that doesn't work}
  \missing{\subsubsectionblock \def subsubsection{subsubsection}\par \@tempskipa \beforesubsubsecskip \relax \let \GenericError {               }{LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item}{See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.}{Try typing  <return>  to proceed.\MessageBreak If that doesn't work}
  \missing{The marquis Federico Cavriani's views}
  \missing{type  X <return>  to quit.}\let \reserved@d =*\def \par}
\endrefsection
\endinput
```

But it's hard for me to understand why \iffalse and "Tex capacity exceeded" errors appear at the same time. I use a template from my university in order to comply with the graduate school's formatting rules. I tried to adapt this template for a dissertation in the humanities and I added the necessary packages.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,oneside,final]{memoir}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,Ligatures={Common}]{Garamond Premier Pro}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage[rightcaption]{sidecap}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{type1cm}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=american]{english}
\setotherlanguage[variant=ancient,numerals=arabic]{greek}
\setotherlanguage[spelling=new]{german}
\setotherlanguages{latin,french,italian,spanish}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{etoolbox,keyval,ifthen}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
%\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{plain}{\cite}{\cites}
\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{plain}{\textcite}{\textcites}
\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{inline}{\textcite}{\textcites}
\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{footnote}[l]{\footcite}{\footcites}
%\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{footnote}[f]{\smartcite}{\smartcites}
\bibliography{masterbib}
\usepackage[final]{hyperref}%?%hyperfootnotes=false
\hypersetup{bookmarks=false,        % show bookmarks bar?
    unicode=true,           % non-Latin characters in Acrobat’s bookmarks
    pdftoolbar=true,        % show Acrobat’s toolbar?
    pdfmenubar=true,        % show Acrobat’s menu?
    pdffitwindow=false,     % window fit to page when opened
    pdfstartview={FitH},    % fits the width of the page to the window
    pdftitle={},
    pdfauthor={XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX},     % author
    pdfsubject={Ph.D. Dissertation},   % subject of the document
    pdfcreator={XXXXXXXXXXXX},   % creator of the document
    pdfproducer={XXXXXXXXXXXXX}, % producer of the document
    pdfkeywords={XXXXXXXXXXXXX}, % list of keywords
    pdfnewwindow=true,      % links in new window
    colorlinks=true,       % false: boxed links; true: colored links
    linkcolor=black,          % color of internal links
    citecolor=black,        % color of links to bibliography
    filecolor=black,      % color of file links
    urlcolor=black           % color of external links
}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{xecolor}
\definergbcolor{blue}{0000FF}
\definergbcolor{red}{FF0000} %\textxecolor{colorname}{text}
\XeTeXdashbreakstate=1
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{outline}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{ccicons}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
%!%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%for non-italicized headings%%%%%
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32655/remove-italic-from-memoir-headings-pagestyle
\makeevenhead{headings}{\leftmark}{}{}
\makeoddhead{headings}{\rightmark}{}{}
\makeevenfoot{headings}{}{\thepage}{}
\makeoddfoot{headings}{}{\thepage}{}

%!%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%!%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%for margins, l=1.5; rest=1.0, maybe add 0.1in%%%%%
\setstocksize{11in}{8.5in}
\settrimmedsize{11.0in}{8.5in}{*} %\settrimmedsize{ height }{ width }{ ratio }
\settypeblocksize{7.75in}{5.8in}{*} %\settypeblocksize{ height }{ width }{ ratio } %note: 7.25h gives margins of 1.5 on top/bottom w/ ubratio of 1
\setlrmargins{1.5in}{*}{*} %\setlrmargins{ spine }{ edge }{ ratio } %spine = left, edge = right; only answer one or two of these values
%\setlrmarginsandblock{1.5in}{1.0in}{*} %\setlrmarginsandblock{ spine }{ edge }{ ratio } %
%\setulmargins{*}{*}{*} %\setulmargins{ upper }{ lower }{ ratio }
%\setulmarginsandblock{0.5in}{*}{*} %\setulmarginsandblock{ upper }{ lower }{ ratio }
%\setheadfoot{*}{*} %\setheadfoot{ headheight }{ footskip }
%\setheaderspaces{1.0in}{*}{*} %\setheaderspaces{ headdrop }{ headsep }{ ratio }
%\checkandfixthelayout[lines]
\flushbottom
%!%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\apptocmd{\sloppy}{\hbadness 10000\relax}{}{}

\setsecnumdepth{subparagraph}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@makefntext{\hspace*{2em}\@thefnmark. }
\newenvironment*{singlespcquote}
        {\quote\SingleSpacing}
        {\endquote}
\SetBlockThreshold{0}
\SetBlockEnvironment{singlespcquote}
\SetCiteCommand{\parencite} %default is \cite

\begin{document}
%\fussy
%\hyphenpenalty=5000   %1000 default=?
%\tolerance=1000        %1000 %200= default
%\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em}
%\midsloppy
\fussy
\vbadness=10000 % badness above which bad vboxes are shown. (Default = 10000?)
\frontmatter
\hyphenation{}

\DoubleSpacing

\begin{center}
```

Comment: (1) Delete all files but the `.tex` one and start anew. (2) Provide a complete, but minimal example that reproduces the problem -- what you have provided is neither complete nor minimal, and it moreover does not cause the problem you are describing since there are no citations in it. (3) Make sure that your version of `Biber` and `biblatex` are compatible (see `biblatex` manual for the list of matched versions). (4 -- not root cause of problem) Take a closer look at your preamble: it loads some packages twice, and others in a haphazard order. (5) Your thesis includes numbered "subparagraphs"?

Comment: Your `.bbl` file looks a bit damaged, indeed. First you should update your TeX distribution to make sure the versions of Biber and `biblatex` match. Then delete all the auxiliary files and try again. If the problem still occurs, try to break it down to a minimal example which you verify to actually exhibit the problem. See [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)

Comment: Many thanks for the answers! Deleting the auxiliary files and updating everything seems to have resolved the problem... for now.

Comment: OK, I will vote to close soon as off-topic because it was solved by an update. (Of course the question is not really off topic, but we don't have any other closing reason)